# SEO relevance of sitewide link to own homepage

Tags: seo, links, homepage, button

Most websites link from every page to the frontpage via a href placed in a logo or home button.

I'm maintaining this website where there isn't such a link per se. Navigation to the homepage is done via a button attached to a form. It makes sense in the context, as the entire menu that the button belongs to is made of more buttons and inputs that dinamically load and sort content.

Is there any loss from a SEO perspective (such as not enough link juice not being passed to the homepage etc.) or, conversely, a gain (like more juice to share between the other pages)? So should I recommend replacing the button with a classical link or just leave it be?

Comment: You are upsetting the balance of the universe by being contrary to the norm... I can feel the wabble beginning... soon the polar ice caps will be melting and Florida will be underwater. Time to buy beachfront property in South Georgia. ;-) You should be fine. It is generally assumed that the home page is the most important page, but you bring up a good point.

Answer (score 1):

Having a link in a button or not it doesn't affect the ranking juice transfer in any way. If it works for you in some practical way you better keep it. It's a harmless little button after all.

Comment: It's not the presence of the button that troubles me but the absence of a link. Do you think it's worth adding it somewhere else maybe?

Answer (score 1):

There's little to no ranking value here.

Just do what is right for your design and users.